# Loading problem of NIB file from TabViewController in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, nib

I have a UITableViewController (MyViewController.xib). This is showing 3 rows with their title. I have 3 new xib file for each row title.On each row selection I want to load XIB file. I am getting the place when I am clicking on RowIndex Selection. But when i am trying to load NIB file nothing is happening. I mean nither program is being crashed nor NIB file is being load.

I am defining my interface declaration here.

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 #import "HistoryShow.h"

@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSArray *tableList;

   IBOutlet HistoryShow *historyController;



}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *tableList;

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet HistoryShow *historyController;

@end
```

My implementation details are below.

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; //typecasting

     if([@"History" isEqual:str])
    {
       NSLog(@"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");   

     HistoryShow *detailViewController = [[[HistoryShow alloc]initWithNibName:@"HistoryShow" bundle:nil]autorelease];

 [historyController release]; 

    } 
}
```

This is prining "!!!!!!" on console but next "HistoryShow.xib" is not being load.

What is the exact problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating `detailViewController`, but you aren't doing anything with it.

Try adding this after the `alloc` of `detailViewController`:

```
[self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: HistoryShow *view2 = [[HistoryShow alloc] initWithNibName:@"HistoryShow" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 
       [self.view addSubview:view2.view]; 
      [historyController release];

Comment: This is working now by the above code changing. anyways thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the view to your present view using `addSubview:` or push the `viewController` using a `navigationController` to see the view.

Something like this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; //typecasting
if([@"History" isEqual:str])
{
NSLog(@"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");   
HistoryShow *detailViewController = [[HistoryShow alloc]initWithNibName:@"HistoryShow" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES]; //  if you have a navigation controller
[detailViewController release]; 
} 
}
```

Comment: The title implies that he's using the Tab View Controller template, so I don't think he'll have a navigation controller to push to.

Comment: I said this was an option. Besides you can have a navigation controller within a tabBarController. thats definitely present in many apps. where u have a navigation controller within a tabitems

Comment: Agreed. Just wasn't sure that he would know that he would need to create a nav controller first.